# Trying to change pandas column dtype from str to float

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a pandas column from a str to a float. Before I convert the strings to floats using astype(float), I need to remove characters from the string which cannot be converted into floats, like a comma or a space. In trying to remove these characters, I am using list compression and the str.replace method like this:

```
data.loc[:,'column_name'] = [char.replace(',', '') for char in 
                                data.loc[:,'column_name']]
```

but I am getting an error saying:

`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'.`

The confusing part, though, is that when I look at the dtypes, the dtype for that column shows up as 'o', or object. So I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: look at set([type(x) for x in data['column_name'].values] - a common problem is that it has some NaN values which are float, not string.

Comment: The question is about programming, not about Data Science, it is better if you move your question to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

In `pandas` the `object` type is used when there is not a clear distinction between the types stored in the column.

**So, I guess that in your column, some objects are `float` type and some objects are `str` type**. Or maybe, you are also dealing with `NaN` objects, `NaN` objects are `float` objects.

**a) Convert the column to string:** Are you getting your DataFrame from a CSV or XLS format file? Then at the moment of reading the file, you can specify that that column is an `str` type or just make the type conversion of the column you are dealing with.

b) After that, you can apply the string changes and/or deal with the NaN objects.

c) Finally, you transform your column into `float` type`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a very rudimentary method but I would just do

```
listt = []
for i in data['column_name']:
     listt.append(float(i))
data['FloatData'] = listt
```